# How to fully rename a react native application without deleting ios/android files

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

The questions already answered have answers that include deleting android/ios files or just plain out of date (suggesting `react-native-rename`. I want to do a full, in-depth rename of the application, package, all generated files everything. I don't want to use `react-native-rename` and i dont want to delete my /ios or /android files

Answer (score 0):

If your code is stored in `github`, you can use this module.

You can run

```
yarn global add react-native-rename
or
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

And

```
git checkout -b rename-app
```

```
react-native-rename <newName>
```

[react-native-rename module npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

Comment: “I don’t want to use react-native-rename”

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just rename the project name

change the name in App.json file

```
 {
  "name": "demochanges",
  "displayName": "demochanges"
}
```

and in Android in mainActivity.java
change the name inside return to the currently changed name in app.js

```
 @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "demochanges";
    }
```

Comment: So doing this, every single instance of “oldAppName” in allll Xcode/android studio files will be changed to “newAppName”?

Comment: Not true. I've done it and it still displays the old name in multiple istances through out all the files.

Comment: when I say FULL rename, I mean every single instance of 'oldAppName' is replaced with 'newAppName'..*everywhere*, as if I `react-native init 'newProjectName'` from the beginning.

Comment: exhibit 1) the applications Icon name is still 'oldAppName'. this is the same situation throughout the rest of the application files

Comment: for ios 
open .workspace project and change the name of the app and it will change the app name

Comment: again, no it doesn't

Comment: this answer actually messed up my project. dont use it.